# Will I take friendly fire from hacked or friendly enemies (security bots, turrets, hypnotized enemies, etc.)?

Tags: bioshock, bioshock-2

Will I take friendly fire from hacked or friendly enemies (security bots, [turrets](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Turret#BioShock_2), hypnotized enemies, etc)?

If I will take friendly fire, what are the enemies' behavior when they are firing and the player character is in their line of sight? Do they stop firing when the player character is in their line of sight? Or should I try to avoid getting in their line of sight to avoid them shooting me?

EDIT: There is now [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102827/4797) that explains how this works for security bots and turrets. Can anyone add or explain how this works for friendly (hypnotized) enemies?

Comment: Can't find anything on this on the wiki. Doesn't seem like it would hurt you though

Answer (score 4):

I'm not positive about charmed enemies, but I can tell you that you will take damage from hacked turrets.

Hacked security bots will usually not be a problem, as they will fly overhead and move around in such a way as to get a direct line of attack. Hacked turrets will fire as long as there's something hostile in their radar, even if you're in the way.

(I frequently forget this when I'm near the entrance to the medical pavilion in *Bioshock*, and the hacked turret in the closet blows me apart trying to kill splicers or that Big Daddy.)

Comment: If you run in front of a hypnotised enemy who is shooting, you will also take damage.